# boost 1.66.0 msvc-14.1 error

Tags: visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to compile boost 1.66.0 on my Windows machine. I've got Visual Studio 2017 (Community) installed as my IDE and the 14.1 compiler definitely works. However, if I try to invoke this inside any of the VC2017 native command prompts

```
.\bootstrap
.\b2 variant=debug,release link=shared,static threading=single,multi address-model=64 toolset=msvc-14.1
```

I get plenty of the following errors:

> 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file

If I change the toolset to msvc-14.0 everything works fine. I've also compiled boost 1.65.1 with msvc-14.1 sucessfully. However, there have been a number of Visual Studio updates since then.

Edit: I've tried compiling boost 1.65.1 again with the most recent compiler version (19.12.25834) and I get the same issue now. Calling "cl" manually inside the "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017" works fine though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to:

- Delete "C:\Users\'username'\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.1_vcvars32_.cmd"
- Build again

My assumtion of reason: Boost makes a temporary "cmd" file which might be from an old build that did not support "msvc-14.1".  The file is not rebuilt/deleted.

Background: 
I had the same issue with one of my two development machines, both very similar (Windows 7) and updated with VC2017.3. The one working complained about the "Unknown version" (_MSC_VER=1911), but completed the building. The failing one had the "cl is not recognized" error.  When looking at the point of failure it explicitly said that it was calling "C:\Users\'username'\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.1_vcvars32_.cmd".

I did a compare at both machines and found that the failing one did not include setting __VSCMD_PREINIT_VCToolsVersion=14.12.25827. There might have been other differences but this one was for sure.

I assumed that I was missing some SW packages or environment settings, but found it strange that the file was not deleted when doing a "b2.exe --toolset=msvc-14.1 --clean-all".

My solution was to delete the temporary cmd file - allowing it to be rebuilt.

After manually deleting "c:\Users\'username'\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_14.1_vcvars32_.cmd", the building worked fine (except for the 1.65.1 complains about the version _MSC_VER=1911).

Comment: This is really useful information, thank you so much.